# How to create dual view for Youtube in Android VR app?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, virtual-reality

I want to create an app that allows you to watch regular Youtube videos in a VR headset (that's normal videos, not VR 360 videos).

Does anyone know how to embed two youtube viewers in the same activity, playing the same video to create the stereoscopic views for a VR type app?

It doesn't seem you can do with with the Youtube Android API as it only lets you play one Youtube viewer at a time.

It's definitely possible, as this app shows ...
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ekm.youtubevr3dvideos

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see the need to do that. There are plenty of videos on youtube that are made for it. Like the google cardboard. Just search for "3D" in tioutube to find.

Comment: I want to wrap some extra functionality around the youtube video playback that doesn't exist in any of the existing apps

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Tempus, you can use the Google Cardboard which lets you experience virtual reality in a simple and fun way. With Cardboard and the YouTube mobile app, you can even watch [360 degree videos](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6178631?hl=en) for an immersive experience.

Also, you can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview) on how to embed VR view.

[**VR View sample code**](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/samples/vrview):
There are two sample apps which demonstrate the [VR View](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview) functionality in the SDK: **simplepanowidget** and **simplevideowidget**. Both of these samples are single activity applications that display an embedded panoramic image or video using [`VrPanoramaView`](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/widgets/pano/VrPanoramaView) and [`VrVideoView`](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/widgets/video/VrVideoView), respectively.

Comment: Thanks, I've got VrVideoView working with streaming an mp4 file from a http uri, but there doesn't seem to be a way to getting it to work with aYoutube video.